# Convert character to date and numeric, maintain same format

Tags: r

In the output of the code below the variables day and sales are in the format that I need but not the type, it outputs type `chr` instead. The variables should be date and num respectively. I've tried many things but either I get `chr` or some sort of error. For instance, using `as.Date()` doesn´t change the variable day to the format `"%d/%m/%Y"`. The code with sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(matrix(c("2017-09-04","2017-09-05",103,104,17356,18022),ncol = 3, nrow = 2)) 
colnames(df) <- c("DATE","ORDER_ID","SALES")
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$SALES <-  as.numeric(as.character(df$SALES))
df$ORDER_ID <-  as.numeric(as.character(df$ORDER_ID))

TOTALSALES <- df %>% 
    select(ORDER_ID,DATE,SALES) %>% 
    mutate(weekday = wday(DATE, label=TRUE)) %>%  
    mutate(DATE=as.Date(DATE)) %>% 
    filter(!wday(DATE) %in% c(1, 7) & !(DATE %in% as.Date(c('2017-01-02','2017-02-27','2017-02-28','2017-04-14'))) ) %>% 
    group_by(day=floor_date(DATE,"day")) %>% 
    summarise(sales=sum(SALES)) %>% 
    data.frame()        
TOTALSALES$day <- TOTALSALES$day %>% 
    as.POSIXlt(, tz="America/Sao_Paulo") %>% 
    format("%d/%m/%Y")
TOTALSALES$sales <- TOTALSALES$sales %>% 
    format(digits=9, decimal.mark=",",nsmall=2,big.mark = ".")
TOTALSALES$day <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem or a direction on how it should be done ?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

To *print* a `Date` object in a particular date-time format you can use `format`

```
# This *converts* a character vector/factor to a vector of Dates
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

# This *prints* the Date vector as a character vector with format "%d/%m/%Y"
format(df$DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

---

Minimal example

```
ss <- c("2017-09-04","2017-09-05")

date <- as.Date(ss, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
format(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "04/09/2017" "05/09/2017"
```

Comment: Hi, It doen't work , I still get  $ DATE    : Date, format: "2017-09-04" "2017-09-05"

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull It does work, see my updated post. I've got a feeling that we're missing each others point. Can you edit your post to include the expected output of `TOTALSALES`?

Comment: Hello, I tried but it doesn´t work : test <- format(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")  >>  str(test)>> chr [1:2] "04/09/2017" "05/09/2017". The output is chr not date type

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull I think you're misunderstand how `format` and `as.Date` work. The latter converts a string (or vector of strings) to a `Date` object. The former converts a `Date` object to a string or (vector of strings). A `Date` object will by default be printed as `"%Y-%m-%d"`. `format` then allows you to change the output format of a printed `Date` object. If you want to convert a vector of strings as `Date`s, simply do `as.Date` and that's it.

Comment: Hello Maurits, thank you for your explanation. I got your point, however what I need is the date object "%Y-%m-%d" to be a date object as "%d/%m/%Y"  format. Just that.

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull In short: That's not possible. As I explain a `Date` object is exactly that: an R object of class `Date`. You can `format` (or print) it in any way you like. You need to understand that a statement like *"I need the date object "%Y-%m-%d" to be a date object as "%d/%m/%Y" format"* does not make any sense. The reason being what I explained in my previous comment. Hence the misunderstanding. If you must have your date in format `"%d/%m/%Y"`, `format` it accordingly but it will be a `character` vector.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Thanks again.